# Bicycle with 26x1.95 tires

Tags: tire, size

Can a bicycle with 26x1.95 tires on magnesium alloy wheels be upgraded? Say 26x2.10?

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Bicycles Stack Exchange. Yes, bike rims can generally take a range of tire widths. The limiting factor is usually the amount of available clearance between the frame chainstays. There are a number of answers here about tire width. See [this one](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52373/i-have-got-29er-tires-and-i-want-to-upgrade-to-29-plus) to start.

Comment: Yes as Argenti said you should have no issues with such a small change, however the deciding factor is clearance on chainstays. It also depends on the width of the wheel/rim but that small of a difference should be fine in that regard. This will likely be closed as there are a lot of similar questions

Comment: One more thing to add to previous answers is that such a bike is made to be light for said application(folding bike). Usually a wider tire is heavier because of the extra materials and extra air(yes it weights). Also you will feel it while pedaling and coasting.

Comment: In general, tires with decimal widths can be replaced with others differing by a half-inch or so with no difficulty relative to the rim (though there may of course be frame clearance issues).  Older tire sizes, with width expressed in fractions, are a different matter, however, as the actual rim diameter often varied with the stated width.

Comment: @dmb Are you sure that folding bikes are built to be light? I would expect a folding bike to be substantially heavier than a non-folding bike of the same size, because it needs extra strength and big, beefy hinges.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Thats why I’ve said “application”. Folding bikes are made to be compact, carriable and light. Just imagine a suit up dude man handling the thing to get on a metrobus

Comment: According to manufacturer it's 16-17kg, in reality probably heavier. I wouldn't call that light. The same company also has 18kg road bike.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time that should work. You have to make sure it isn’t a Schwinn special sizing (Any of the S(1-6) sizing). Make sure the tire ISO and wheel are 559mm.

For this bike, I would say with 99% confidence that would work.

Personally, I would look elsewhere if you were looking to upgrade something. A used bike from a reputable brand on Craigslist will perform a lot better for the same cost.